# control GPU fan speed AMD RADEON RX 590

Tags: 20.04, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed alongside windows as dual boot system. When running Windows the fans are quiet but running Ubuntu the fans are louder than normally is on windows. I would like to be able to control fan speed on my system. I've tried tools like `lm-sensors` and `fancontrol` without success. Is there any software out there which allows me to do that ?

Comment: does `sensors-detect` find anything?  What modules end up loaded?

Comment: yes. `# Chip drivers
nct6775
`

Comment: I managed to make it work here recently `https://github.com/grmat/amdgpu-fancontrol`. I would like to use `fancontrol` but i don't see any easy to understand tutorial on how to configure the fan.

Comment: Interesting, I can see pwm for my amd is enabled at `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm1_enable` and I can set pwm1 to 255 and the fans kick on, but something else is actively controlling it and turns the fans off within 10 seconds, and its not fancontrol.  I'm curious if amdgpu-fancontrol is acting the way you think it should if there is another process controlling it.  Maybe the radeon module is doing it, or the firmware, idk.